# Dynamically change position of grid layout items

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a grid layout that shows images like on the image bellow. I want to be able to swap two images at any position.

[image: Grid of images]

The hierarchy is like this:

ScrollArea->GridLayout->Label[n]->Pixmap

There are **n** labels in the grid layout created dynamically in the code.

It is possible to delete everything an create again in the column/row I want, but I'm trying to find a more elegant way to do this. Any tips?

Comment: I would do that with a table view instead of handling a grid layout.

Comment: Not sure it table will help me. There will be some changing in position, columns and rows. Is there a way to automatic rearrange the items I remove a column?

Comment: What I can say is that table views are much flexible than layout if speak about dynamically changing content. Qt layouts are mostly for static GUI elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to use a grid layout...

```
void YourClass::swapWidgets(QWidget *widgetA, QWidget *widgetB)
{
    int indexA = yourGridLayout->indexOf(widgetA);
    int indexB = yourGridLayout->indexOf(widgetB);
    int row1, column1, rowSpan1, columnSpan1;
    int row2, column2, rowSpan2, columnSpan2;

    yourGridLayout->getItemPosition(indexA, &row1, &column1, &rowSpan1, &columnSpan1);
    yourGridLayout->getItemPosition(indexB, &row2, &column2, &rowSpan2, &columnSpan2);

    yourGridLayout->takeAt(indexA);
    yourGridLayout->takeAt(indexB);

    yourGridLayout->addWidget(widgetB, row1, column1, rowSpan1, columnSpan1);
    yourGridLayout->addWidget(widgetA, row2, column2, rowSpan2, columnSpan2);
}
```

Comment: calling QGridLayout::addWidget leaks memory, why ?

Comment: don't forget to delete the QLayoutItem pointer returned by takeAt, otherwise, memory will be leaked (https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/70354-Dynamically-change-position-of-grid-layout-items)

Comment: Why not add the item returned by `takeAt` and put it back into the layout with `addItem`?